# Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'Google' was added by build file 'build.gradle'

Tags: gradle, printing, build.gradle, printers, thermal-printer

A problem occurred evaluating root project when adding allprojects{}.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserCodeException: Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'Google' was added by build file 'build.gradle'

Here is the code in build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()

}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21"
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 14):

For Android Studio Arctic Fox |2020.3.1
Remove this from the **build.gradle**

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
```

}
Go to **settings.gradle** and add follwing line

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
```

}

Comment: This solution solved my problem! Thanks a lot for you answer! \O/

Answer (score 0):

For Spring Boot gradle project this one of the ways by which you can specify **build.gradle**

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
maven {
            url can be given like this "https://plugins.gradle.org/"
        }
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'Google' was added by build file 'build.gradle'

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings.gradle and update as shown

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
```